# When and how to close a connection in case of a asynchronous message listener?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Below a connection is created, and then a session, and then a certain amount of messages should be  taken from the queue.

```
public class Consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(); // creates a connection and session

        Destination destination = consumer.getSession().createQueue("JOBS"); 
        MessageConsumer messageConsumer = consumer.getSession().createConsumer(destination);
        messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new Listener(job)); // asynchronous listener.

        consumer.close(); // closes the connection
    }
}
```

When and how can I close the connection? Because when I do it as above, only one message is read!
If I do not close the connection as above, all the messages are read, so that is OK, but the connection stays open.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to decide when to close the connection.

You can add a Thread.sleep before closing or add a **shutdownHook** to close when the jam stops :

```
Thread shutdownHook = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           consumer.close();
        }
    });  

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
```

Another approach :

> The maximum inactivity duration (before which the socket is considered
>   dead) in milliseconds. On some platforms it can take a long time for a
>   socket to appear to die, so we allow the broker to kill connections if
>   they are inactive for a period of time. Use by some transports to
>   enable a keep alive heart beat feature. Set to a value <= 0 to disable
>   inactivity monitoring.

you can specify maximum inactivity duration for the connections using wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration, for this when you are creating a connection with MQ broker then you should create like this

```
cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
    "tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat=openwire&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=value");
```

Read this ActiveMQ documentation for more details http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html